# MySQL Joining multiple tables with where clause result is too slow

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have the following structure of tables;

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
-                       table1                            -
- id(PK) | date_created | column1 | t2_id | t3_id | t4_id -
- 1        ...            sample       1       1      1   -
- 2        ...            sample       2       2      2   -
- 3        ...            sample       3       3      3   -
-----------------------------------------------------------

-------------------     --------------------    -------------------- 
-     table2       -    -     table3       -    -     table4       -
- id(PK) | column1 -    - id(PK) | column1 -    - id(PK) | column1 -
- 1        sample  -    - 1        sample  -    - 1        sample  -
- 2        sample  -    - 2        sample  -    - 2        sample  -
- 3        sample  -    - 3        sample  -    - 3        sample  -
--------------------    --------------------    --------------------
```

and I want a result of;

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-date_created | column1 | table2.column1 | table3.column1  | table4.column1  -
-   ...         sample        sample           sample             sample     -
-   ...         sample        sample           sample             sample     -
-   ...         sample        sample           sample             sample     -
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I used the following query;

```
SELECT 
table1.date_created, table1.column1, 
table2.column1,
table3.column1, 
table4.column1
FROM 
table1, table2, table3, table4
WHERE
table2.id = table1.t2_id AND
table3.id = table1.t3_id AND
table4.id = table1.t4_id
ORDER BY table1.date_created DESC
```

I still have other tables that are connected to table1. The problem is the result is too slow even though there are only three results. I'm not that good at databases maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Is `id` the `PRIMARY KEY` of each table?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: YES, the id is the primary key of each table.

Comment: How many rows in each table?  Is `date_created` indexed?

Comment: As of now, I only have three rows for each table. I don't know what do you mean by indexed, but the value of date_created is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Are there foreign keys relationship between table1 and the others?

Comment: The value of `t2_id`, `t3_id`, `t4_id`, and so on from `table1` is simply the `ID's` of `table2`, `table3`, `table4`, and so on. (Correct me if I'm wrong) so I guess, that's a foreign key?

Comment: You need to optimize your database, probably normalize it. Remember that Joining the table will make your query very slow especially if you have 16 tables that are related to `table1` on their own id like what you said in the comment. AND if you don't know if there are foreign keys on your table, then there is none, because if you assign it then you should know. Keep your database structure simple if possible and try to avoid the use of Join in a large table.

Comment: The problem is I can't avoid using the Join on my table. The reason why I have 16 tables is to avoid duplicate entries. For example, in my `table 1` all `names` should be store in there, and if the name already exists then get only the id of it and store it in `table1` same with the other tables. Then in a single query, I want to fetch all values from other tables using the ids from `table1`.

Comment: Your normalization from other tables might be correct because you are trying to avoid duplicate entries. But if you have 16 tables and those ids are stored on `table1` plus the other column such as `date_created`, `column1` then you now have 18 columns on a single table. There might be no problem if you just want to query on `table1` but since you want to fetch all values from other tables using Join then you'll get a very slow query. I suggest either normalize your `table1`  or fetch only the column you really need at a time. I doubt you need all those columns on a single view.

Comment: For example, if you only need the value from `table2` and `table3` then limit the column on your query for `table2.column1` and `table3.column` only.

Comment: Also, make use of INDEX like what @RickJames answered.

Comment: I think of what you said and I realized that I really don't need to get all those values from other tables in a single query. I just query the columns that I need and you are right, the result is now faster. I'm thinking if I can still normalize my `table1` to make it much faster. Thank you so much! Please make an answer so I can accept.

Comment: Please elaborate on the need for 16 tables.  And, will you need 17 tomorrow?

Comment: @RickJames The 16 tables contain the data that is related to `table1`. I used it to avoid duplicate entries, you all people called it `Nomalization` or whatsover but I like the idea. For example, one of the tables has a list of names. If the user input the same name, then no need to store it, I just get the id of it and store in the `table1`. Now, if I want to get the list of names that is related to another table then I just make a query from `table1` and join the table that contains the list of names.

Comment: @Bolomeo - I might understand better if you used real names instead of "table1", "column1", and "sample".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, always remember that **using `JOIN` on a large table will make your query very slow**. Your database structure is already considered large since you have 16 tables that are related to the `table1`(That makes them 17) plus the number of data.

You only have four rows in every table at the moment, it is worth it if you mention the span time of the result of your query so we have a baseline on how slow is it and we don't just assume.

Anyway, dividing those tables into multiple to avoid duplicate entries is a good normalization. However, you must think again about the `table1`. This is the core of the relation between your tables so you must know how to handle this properly.

The solution is to create an index of every table, see [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) answer.
Then use `LEFT JOIN` so you get every row even the corresponding table is empty or the ID didn't match.

```
SELECT 

t1.date_created, 
t1.column1, 
t2.column1, 
t3.column1, 
t4.column1

FROM table1 t1 

LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.t2_id 
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.id = t1.t3_id 
LEFT JOIN table4 t4 ON t4.id = t1.t4_id

ORDER BY t1.date_created DESC;
```

Then finally, pick only the column from the specific table that you really need. This is how you can enhance your query. Don't just query it all, be smart on which data you just need.

Answer (score 1):

First, rewrite the query using explicit `JOIN`s.  There is no need whatsoever to use archaic syntax:

```
SELECT t1.date_created, t1.column1, 
       t2.column1, t3.column1, t4.column1
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t2.id = t1.t2_id JOIN
     table3 t3
     ON t3.id = t1.t3_id JOIN
     table4 t4
     ON t4.id = t1.t4_id
ORDER BY t1.date_created DESC;
```

Then you want indexes on all the tables apart from `table1` for the joins:

```
create index idx_table2_id_column1 on table2(id, column1);
create index idx_table3_id_column1 on table3(id, column1);
create index idx_table4_id_column1 on table4(id, column1);
```

These indexes are not necessary if the `id` is the primary key of the table.

Finally, you can use an index on `table1` as well to handle the `order by`:

```
create index idx_table1_date_created_t2id_t3id_t4id_column1 on table1(date_created desc, t2_id, t3_id, t4_id, column1);
```

The first key is the most important here.  The rest just allow the index to cover the query which can be a modest win for performance.

Comment: I didn't try yet the query. Is there any difference in performance by using `explicit JOIN`? I agreed to @DeanTaler about the query, it is much cleaner compared to my original query so I've used it but nothing change in performance. Since I have more tables, I think this `explicit JOIN`n will make me confuse. But if it does make changes to performance then I will use it even if I get confused.

Comment: Anyway, from what I understand, the `INDEX` is the one that will make the query faster right?

Comment: @Bolomeo . . . Explicit joins should have similar performance characteristics to the archaic `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Remember that this will return empty rows if one of the tables is empty or the corresponding ID doesn't match. You may try using `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
table1.date_created, table1.column1, 
table2.column1,
table3.column1, 
table4.column1
FROM 
table1
inner join table2 on table2.id = table1.t2_id 
inner join table3 on table3.id = table1.t3_id
inner join table4 on table4.id = table1.t4_id
ORDER BY table1.date_created DESC
```

Comment: This is the preferred way to write `JOINs`, but it is no faster than the OP's.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, do

```
ALTER TABLE table1
    ADD INDEX(date_created);
```

Comment: Still have the same issue. Could it be that I have multiple tables? I have 16 tables, the structure is the same with `table2`, `table3`, and `table4`, and their `ID's` is stored on `table1` so that I can query specific column base on the id.